# What's the meaning of this error message in error log?

Tags: security, cpanel, error-log

In my shared hosting account, I noticed the following error in the Error Log of CPanel under Main Error Log.

I need to know what's the danger of this error, where we see the words *victim* and *attacker* ? and what's it mean?

> [Wed Nov 14 16:26:28 2012] [error] [client xx.163.xxx.xxx] Caught race
>   condition abuser. attacker: 2194, victim: 0 open file owner: 0,
>   referer: http://www.orleansren.com/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably this: http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@httpd.apache.org/msg55666.html, but is probably not an issue unless you are the website listed: http://www.orleansren.com/. There was the opportunity for some one to change a symlink while it was being accessed. You seeing this message means it has been patched.

Answer (score 2):

Bad permission or ownership can also trigger this error. I have resolved it by changing ownership of my application directory. It was owned by root before.

Check file ownership by

`ls -la filename`

If it is not owned by your user, login as super user and change ownership.

`chown myuser:myuser filename`

Comment: I am caught in a similar issue like this where I am unable to a delete a folder from the cpanel or to change its ownership? Wanna suggest anything? Thanks

Comment: Check file permission by `ls -la filename`. If it is not owned by your user, login as super user and change ownership.

Comment: Every file and directory inside that folder is owned by root. I have logged in as a user. Could you please tell me how to login as a root? And please check these screenshots also https://i.imgur.com/47Qwf2l.png and https://i.imgur.com/Lf5t4Le.png

Comment: Do a complete ownership change. `chown -R myuser:myuser homedir`

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: This error came when I executed this command: "rpws is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: You don't have sudo privilege. Ask your hosting support to fix this.